# Compatibility issue with rasa

Tags: chatbot, rasa

Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (dialogue_encoder/strided_slice_4:0) to a numpy array.

I am getting this error with using rasa==1.10.3 having tensorflow of 2.2 and numpy==1.18.5

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade numpy to numpy 1.19.5

```
pip install numpy==1.19.5
```

This should fix the problem.

Also for Rasa's version, I am afraid `rasa==1.10.3` is not a supported version. You can check the Compatibility Matrix from here:
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/changelog/compatibility-matrix/